# Trying to save data from Gravity Forms to a Microsoft SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, wordpress, plugins, gravityforms

Attemping to make a plugin for Wordpress that saves data submitted from a Gravity Form into a remote MSSQL database. This is in the very early stages but when I click my 'Test Connection' button, my AJAX returns Connection test failed: Internal Server Error. I can't seem to track down what's going on. Would anyone be able to assist. My Plugin code looks like this so far.

```
function gravity_forms_sql_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Gravity Forms SQL Settings</h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('gravity-forms-sql-settings-group'); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections('gravity-forms-sql-settings-group'); ?>
            <?php
            if (extension_loaded('sqlsrv')) {
                echo 'sqlsrv extension is installed.';
            } else {
                echo 'sqlsrv extension is not installed.';
            }
            ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Hostname</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="gravity_forms_sql_hostname" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('gravity_forms_sql_hostname')); ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Username</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="gravity_forms_sql_username" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('gravity_forms_sql_username')); ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Password</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="gravity_forms_sql_password" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('gravity_forms_sql_password')); ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Database Name</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="gravity_forms_sql_database" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('gravity_forms_sql_database')); ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
        <br>
        <button class="button button-primary" id="gravity-forms-sql-test-connection">Test Connection</button>
        <p id="gravity-forms-sql-test-connection-result"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#gravity-forms-sql-test-connection').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var hostname = $('[name="gravity_forms_sql_hostname"]').val();
                var username = $('[name="gravity_forms_sql_username"]').val();
                var password = $('[name="gravity_forms_sql_password"]').val();

                // AJAX request to test the connection
                $.ajax({
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        action: 'gravity_forms_sql_test_connection',
                        hostname: hostname,
                        username: username,
                        password: password
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        var result = response.data; // Extract the result from the response object

                        if (result === 'success') {
                            $('#gravity-forms-sql-test-connection-result').text('Connection test succeeded!');
                        } else {
                            var errorMessage = 'Connection test failed: ' + result;
                            $('#gravity-forms-sql-test-connection-result').text(errorMessage);
                            error_log('An error occurred during the AJAX request.');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                        var errorMessage = 'Connection test failed: ' + error;
                        $('#gravity-forms-sql-test-connection-result').text(errorMessage);
                        error_log('An error occurred during the AJAX request.');
                        console.error('AJAX Error:', error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function gravity_forms_sql_test_connection_callback() {
    $hostname = $_POST['hostname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Disable SSL verification
    $options = [
        PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY => true,
        PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_SSL_OPTIONS => [
            'Encrypt' => 1,
            'TrustServerCertificate' => 1
        ]
    ];

    try {
        $connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$database", $username, $password, $options);
        wp_send_json_success('success'); // Send a success response
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        wp_send_json_error($e->getMessage()); // Send the error message as the response
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_gravity_forms_sql_test_connection', 'gravity_forms_sql_test_connection_callback');

function gravity_forms_sql_register_settings() {
    add_option('gravity_forms_sql_hostname', '');
    add_option('gravity_forms_sql_username', '');
    add_option('gravity_forms_sql_password', '');
    add_option('gravity_forms_sql_database', '');
    add_option('gravity_forms_sql_test_result', '');

    register_setting('gravity-forms-sql-settings-group', 'gravity_forms_sql_hostname');
    register_setting('gravity-forms-sql-settings-group', 'gravity_forms_sql_username');
    register_setting('gravity-forms-sql-settings-group', 'gravity_forms_sql_password');
    register_setting('gravity-forms-sql-settings-group', 'gravity_forms_sql_database');
    register_setting('gravity-forms-sql-settings-group', 'gravity_forms_sql_test_result');
}

function gravity_forms_sql_register_options_page() {
    add_options_page('Gravity Forms SQL', 'Gravity Forms SQL', 'manage_options', 'gravity-forms-sql', 'gravity_forms_sql_settings_page');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'gravity_forms_sql_register_settings');
add_action('admin_menu', 'gravity_forms_sql_register_options_page');

function gravity_forms_sql_save_data($entry, $form) {
    // Get the submitted form data
    $data = $entry['values'];

    // Get the SQL Server connection details from the plugin settings
    $hostname = get_option('gravity_forms_sql_hostname');
    $username = get_option('gravity_forms_sql_username');
    $password = get_option('gravity_forms_sql_password');
    $database = get_option('gravity_forms_sql_database');

    // Connect to the SQL Server
    $connectionString = "sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$database;TrustServerCertificate=true";
    $connection = new PDO($connectionString, $username, $password);

    // Prepare the SQL statement
    $statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO your_table_name (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (:field1, :field2, :field3)");

    // Bind the form data to the statement parameters
    $statement->bindParam(':field1', $data['field1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':field2', $data['field2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':field3', $data['field3'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // Execute the SQL statement
    $statement->execute();
}

add_action('gform_after_submission', 'gravity_forms_sql_save_data', 10, 2);
```

I've ensured that the sqlsrv extension is installed.

Comment: Is there an entry in the error log to explain the Internal Server Error?